# How to chain AngularJS filters in controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have few filters in view

```
  <tr ng-repeat="x in list | filter:search| offset:currentPage*pageSize| limitTo:pageSize ">
```

In my project to achieve good result, i have to make this filtering in controller not in view

i know the basic syntax `$filter('filter')('x','x')` but i don't know how to make chain of filters in controller, so everything will work as in my example from template.

I found some solution, now just with one filter, but should work with many ;)

```
       $scope.data = data; //my geojson from factory//

       $scope.geojson = {}; //i have to make empty object to extend it scope later with data, it is solution i found for leaflet //

       $scope.geojson.data = [];

       $scope.FilteredGeojson = function() {

       var result = $scope.data;

       if ($scope.data) {
          result = $filter('limitTo')(result,10);
          $scope.geojson.data = result;
          console.log('success');
       }
           return result;

       };
```

and i use this function in ng-repeat works fine, but i have to check it with few filters.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can just re-filter what you get returned from your first filter. So on and so forth.

```
var filtered;
filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.list, {name: $scope.filterParams.nameSearch});
filtered = $filter('orderBy')(filtered, $scope.filterParams.order);
```

Below plunkr demonstrates the above.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ej1O36aOrHoNdTMxH2vH?p=preview

Comment: Nice thanks for help, i will try your solution, but i found some idea as well, just updated post.

Comment: Doing it in your way working better then my ;), but if you could just look on my example which i added latter to the question, my way with conditionals works fine with one filter, but i don't know how to add few filters in conditional way, is still possible to do it somehow similar to your way? it is just my curiosity ;)

Comment: not a good solution from performance perspective, as it iterates your list multiple times, this can be a problem if you have large data set.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to explicitly applying filters to the result of the previous one you could also build an object that will chain multiple filters together.

#### Controller

```
angular.module('Demo', []);

angular.module('Demo')
    .controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {

        $scope.order = 'calories';
        $scope.filteredFruits = $scope.fruits = [{ name: 'Apple', calories: 80 }, { name: 'Grapes', calories: 100 }, { name: 'Lemon', calories: 25 }, { name: 'Lime', calories: 20 }, { name: 'Peach', calories: 85 }, { name: 'Orange',    calories: 75 }, { name: 'Strawberry', calories: 65 }];

        $scope.filterFruits = function(){
            var chain = new filterChain($scope.fruits);
            $scope.filteredFruits = chain
                .applyFilter('filter', [{ name: $scope.filter }])
                .applyFilter('orderBy', [ $scope.order ])
                .value;
        };

        function filterChain(value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        filterChain.prototype.applyFilter = function(filterName, args) {
            args.unshift(this.value);
            this.value = $filter(filterName).apply(undefined, args)
            return this;
        };
    });
```

#### View

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="Demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="filter" ng-change="filterFruits()" placeholder="Filter Fruits" />
  <select ng-model="order">
    <option value="name">name</option>
    <option value="calories">calories</option>
  </select>
  <div ng-repeat="fruit in filteredFruits">
    <strong>Name:</strong> {{fruit.name}}
    <strong>Calories:</strong> {{fruit.calories}}
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a typical case for FP libraries like lodash or Ramda. Make sure your common data is applied as last arg to each filter. (in this case columns)

```
$scope.columnDefs = _.compose(
    $filter('filter3'),
    $filter('filter2'),
    $filter('filter1')
)($scope.columns)
```

or with extra args

```
$scope.columnDefs = _.compose(
    $filter('filter3').bind(null, optionalArg1, optionalArg2),
    $filter('filter2').bind(null, optionalArg1),
    $filter('filter1')
)($scope.columns)
```