# AngularJS - Multiple Filters usage in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I want to use multiple filters in controller

Currently using

```
$filter('limitTo')($filter('lowercase')($filter('translate')('ACTIVE')), 5)
```

If we have more filters like this. How can I use multiple filters in controller rather conventional format like this?

Comment: What's your question exactly? The question has the answer: you're already using multiple filters in the controller.

Comment: I am using multiple filters @JB Nizet. Simplified format I want than this.

Comment: similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852445/how-to-chain-angularjs-filters-in-controller

Answer (score 3):

You can simply introduce variables:

```
var limitTo = $filter('limitTo');
var lowercase = $filter('lowercase');
var translate = $filter('translate');

var filteredValue = limitTo(lowercase(translate('ACTIVE')), 5);
```

Or even

```
var lowercaseStatus = lowercase(translate('ACTIVE'));
var filteredValue = limitTo(lowercaseStatus, 5);
```

Another strategy would be to use the same syntax as in the view:

```
var filteredValue = $scope.$eval('"ACTIVE" | translate | lowercase | limitTo:5');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. Usually you would do something like that or something like this:

```
var translatedValue = $filter('translate')('ACTIVE');
var lowercaseValue = $filter('lowercase')(translatedValue);
$scope.finalValue = $filter('limitTo')(lowercaseValue, 5)
```

I created a service inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27853144/3176651).

```
app.service('FilterChain', 
['$filter', function($filter) {
    var chain = {
        value : '',
        start : function(value) {
            this.value = value;
            return this;
        },
        applyFilter : function(filterName, args) {
            args = args || [];
            args.unshift(this.value);
            this.value = $filter(filterName).apply(undefined, args)
            return this;
        }
    };

    return chain;
}]);
```

Usage is like this

```
$scope.value = FilterChain.start('Active')
                .applyFilter('translate')
                .applyFilter('limitTo', [5])
                .applyFilter('uppercase')
                .value;
```

You can use the service with other filters and objects such as arrays. See a working example here: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/happysmiles/sph68qg8/)